# Adding \n into a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to write some code for unity in c#. I am having a problem wring \n into a List. Heres my code.

```
public static List<string> ChatHeads = null;
public void Start()
{
    ChatHeads = new List<string>();
}

void Update()
{
    ChatBoxMessage.text = GetChatHead();
}

string GetChatHead()
{
    return string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, ChatHeads.ToArray());
}

public void MainFunc()
 {
    string FinalMessage = "";

    if (FinalMessage.Length >= 82 || !.inWorld)
    {
        FinalMessage = Message + "\n";
        ChatHeads.Add(FinalMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        FinalMessage = "[" + username + "] " + MainWorld.ChatTag + Message + "\n";
        ChatHeads.Add(FinalMessage);
     }
 }
```

The issue is GetChatHead() only returns the first array string if \n isnt the last part of the string. code works fine as long as the \n appears but it NEVER does always disappears.
thanks.

Pic to List array, No \n at end of any lines.

[image: Pic to List array, No \n at end of any lines.]
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPADz.jpg)

Comment: im not quite sure why you are fetching the chatbox message as an array. can you explain? what is the reason behind needing to specify a new line at a certain number of characters?

Comment: "GetChatHead() only returns the first array string " It looks like the method is not the problem. How do you display it? what is `ChatBoxMessage` ?  up to now I cannot reproduce your problem. The posted array results in a text of 7 lines when I try it. Is this the example where `GetChatHead()` returns only one line?

Comment: Text ChatBoxMessage = GameObject.Find("ChatBoxMessage").GetComponent<Text>();

Comment: gameobject in unity.

Comment: Ironically if i add FinalMessage = Message + "\n";
        ChatHeads.Add(FinalMessage); to the onGUI() and use the text from the InputField it adds the \n and the whole thing works correctly. but i cant have it there because the strings being added to the List are in a different class.

Comment: The core question, "GetChatHead() only returns the first array string if \n isnt the last part of the string" is very unclear. Last part of what string, how did you verify this?  And where does GameObject.Find() come in?  Write a [mcve]. You will probably need more hat one.

Comment: I guess the problem is in the adding of elements to the list or in the display of it (assignment of the `Text`). Up to now the posted code does not include enough information (for me at least) to be able to help you.

Comment: I will add a picture that might show it better. which actually is not attached to unity as a script so normal c#

Comment: no matter how i have it it never appears in the line. @"\n", + "\n", "char(0)". all of them never add \n to the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Apparently Encoding.Default.GetString() wont allow you to add anything to the string.

```
Message = Encoding.Default.GetString(packet.ReadBytes((int)Length));
```

No Good

`Message = packet.ReadString();`

Worked.